# Losing 'this' scope in a Vue + Vuex + Phaser reactive call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, phaser-framework, vuex

I was trying to make a game using Vue + Vuex, but in the middle of the project I realised that the most interactive part of the game had to be made with Phaser, then I decided to use Phaser for that part and keep the Vue + Vuex for the UI.

Everything was going better than expected until I tried to get the first data from Vuex in Phaser, the problem is that I lose the scope of the current object.

I'm using `store.watch();` to get the changes but When I try to call other functions I get an error.

```
import store from '../vuex/store';
import Creature from './Creature';
const creatures = [];
export default {
  create() {
    store.watch(this._newCreatureGetter, this._newCreatureRX);
    for (const creature of this._creaturesGetter()) {
      this._addCreature(creature);
    }
  },
  _addCreature(creature) {
    creatures.push(new Creature(this.game, creature));
  },
  _newCreatureGetter() {
    return store.state.newCreature;
  },
  _newCreatureRX(newCreature) {
    console.log(this);
    this._addCreature(newCreature);
  },
};
```

In this code from Phaser the `_newCreatureRX` is called by VueX, when I try to call `_addCreature` I get an error telling that `_addCreature` is not defined. The `console.log(this)` shows an Vue object.

How do I get this to work properly? Do I Have to structure my project differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store.watch` method will not execute the callback function in the original context, that is why `this` is incorrect.

You can explicitly [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the function to the correct context though

```
store.watch(this._newCreatureGetter, this._newCreatureRX.bind(this))
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I didn't know that i could send a callback with .bind(this). It makes perfect sense now!

Comment: It's easy to miss. The problem is because in Vue.js, it executes the callback via `cb.call(vm, watcher.value)` where `vm` is the `Vue` instance. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/769c4dc2032251323c8f61ad8eba2c26c615a618/src/core/instance/state.js#L228